# xcode add a counter to our game

Tags: iphone, animation, uiimageview, counter

How can we add a counter to our application. For example : when image 1 touch image 2 count++; and for example if count =10 finish the game .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to you the interface of your view controller:

```
NSInteger counter;
```

Add this to the implementation of your view controller:

```
- (id)init {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        // some other initialization
        counter = 0;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)imagePressed: (id)sender {
    counter++;
}
```

Add a transparent button to your view and add an action with selector imagePressed:.

When this answer isn't useful maybe you could improve your question. And please post some code!

Comment: well how can I now for example if counter =10 do something

Comment: Add an if-statement in the imagePressed method and call another method in this if statement.

Answer (score 0):

I sometimes use 2 ways to do this...

```
if (Score == 10){
   //Do something here
}
```

thats pretty straight forward but you can also do it this way...

```
if ([score.text isEqual:@"10"]) {
    //Do something here maybe just display a button.
    buttonNext.hidden = NO;
}
```

I don't know if this helped, but it's a start.

Cheers!